# JSP Date validation

Tags: javascript, jsp, validation, date

I have an jsp page where the user selects two dates. I need to validate this date to ensure that the 1st date is not less than today's date. This is the script I am using:

```
var todaysDate = new Date();

if(document.frm.rentedOnDate.value < todaysDate )
{
  alert("Rented date should not be before today");
  document.frm.bank.focus();
  return false;  
}

if(document.frm.rentedOnDate.value> document.frm.returnDate.value )
{
  alert("Return date should be after rented date");
  document.frm.bank.focus();
  return false;  
}
```

These are the date selection fields:

```
<p>Select Rental Date: &nbsp;<input type="date" name="rentedOnDate"> </p>
<p>Select Return Date: &nbsp;<input type="date" name="returnDate"> </p>
```

The second script function works when the user enters a return date which is before the rented date but the first function does not work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second test is comparing strings, so I wouldn't count on it being perfectly reliable (a preceding zero could break it for instance).

You need to convert the strings (the `.value` fields) to proper date objects, and then compare them.  This will resolve your first check, and improve your second check.

This function will parse a date provided in the "yyyy-mm-dd" fashion (optional 2-digit year yields 20xx).  null is returned for an invalid date.

```
function getDate(str)
{
    var dateParts = /^(\d\d(?:\d\d)?)-(\d\d?)-(\d\d?)$/.exec(str);
    if (dateParts === null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var year = parseInt(dateParts[1]);
    if (year < 100)
    {
        year += 2000;
    }
    var month = parseInt(dateParts[2]) - 1;
    var day = parseInt(dateParts[3]);
    var result = new Date(year, month, day);
    return year === result.getFullYear() 
            && month === result.getMonth()
            && day === result.getDate() ? result : null;
}
```

Comment: I used this: var d1 = new Date(document.frm.rentedOnDate) and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
function validateDate(dates){
    re = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;     
    var days=new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);

    if(regs = dates.match(re)) {
        // day value between 1 and 31
        if(regs[1] < 1 || regs[1] > 31) {                    
          return false;
        }
        // month value between 1 and 12
        if(regs[2] < 1 || regs[2] > 12) {                         
          return false;
        }

        var maxday=days[regs[2]-1];

        if(regs[2]==2){
            if(regs[3]%4==0){
                maxday=maxday+1;                                
            }
        }

        if(regs[1]>maxday){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }                     
}
```

Comment: the above function will handle all cases.